# Django-admin with callable functions

Tags: django, django-admin

Django-admin view allows only for changing the values of model objects. Is it, however, possible to configure or change in an easy way the admin view so that it starts exposing functions on objects? I'm not talking about the functions that can be introduced in the drop-down menu on top of the object list. What I mean is a direct access to functions on model objects?

Comment: I think that's as close as you're gonna get -- the actions.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own view to the admin site by adding an "^admin/..." url in your url conf.  You can use this to extend the admin site relatively easy and expose model methods through your own view.  See `Creating Custom Admin Views` here: http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter17/ (and another approach and notes here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites ).

To add this as a button in the model's "change form" in the admin site, override the `change_form.html` template for the required models (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates ).

You will probably want to override the object-tools block, which holds the buttons in the top right side of the page.  (In Django 1.3 you can extend the object-tools-items block instead, see: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12694 )

(I am quite sure one can build a nice plugin/app that automatically adds object-tools to a model from a custom "object_tools" property in the ModelAdmin with a list of model methods.  Let me know id you find something like this.)