# Image editor for django admin

Tags: python, django-admin

I need some image editor or something else for editing image after upload, for example to resize, to rotate etc. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Picnik API is no longer active (google shut it down after acquiring it), but there is a Picnik compatible API at picmonkey.com.

Docs at https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1OhlOYcCvJiV44c13XpDx0HJV3UArKgRya3lq_Ahr5T0

Answer (score 2):

[django-photologue](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/) can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using django with FotoFlexer, Picnik and pixlr is discussed here: http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/using-web-based-image-editors-django-apps/ .

To add this to the admin, add an object_tool with the link to the editor as described here: [Django-admin with callable functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811927/django-admin-with-callable-functions/6245969#6245969) .